# Submit Form with AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

I would like to submit a very simple form with an XMLHttpRequest. (I don't want to bother with jQuery). All this form does is insert a full name, a username, and a password into our db. I would like for the row to be inserted into the db without refreshing the page, and have the php file send a message back on whether it inserted the row or not. I have experience with creating a live search with AJAX, but have limited experience with submitting forms.

Code samples of an ajax call, along with a sample form would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: first result on google for "javascript xhr post example": http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax_xmlhttp_using_post.php

Comment: it can be a simple button click event which calls the xmlhttprequst and finish the work , no need to use even submit button

Comment: SO is not a tutorial place in essence, try Google for some tutorials.

Comment: I'm having issues posting the variables to the php script...I believe my issue is with the xmlhttp.send()

Comment: just wanted everyone to know i figured it out. I was passing my parameters incorrectly

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a good example of this here: http://www.captain.at/howto-ajax-form-post-get.php